# paramiko sftp function listdir wrong number files

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I'm trying to make a little script with paramiko and python.
I got to connect to my server.

But when i'm trying to make a listdir function all my file are not listed.
All my path are correct.

Remote ssh console

```
ls md5sum_files/ | wc -l
51
```

So i have 51 file in my folder but when i'm doing
Python Code

```
list_file= sftp.listdir(remotepath)
print len(list_file)
```

The output given is changing sometime it give me 6 elem, sometime 7, sometime 10.

I'm sure to look for the good remote folder (only one folder in my Home).
They're is the solution of taring the folder before getting it, but i don't want to have to tar each files for each transfert.

For what it could be important, i'm under Windows, using python 2.7.8 and Pycharm.

The complete Function copy recursive:

```
def recursive_copy(localpath, remotepath, sftp):
    list_file= sftp.listdir(remotepath)
    print len(list_file)
    print list_file
    for fil in list_file:
      print fil
      p1, p2 = "%s/%s" % (remotepath, fil), "%s\%s" % ( localpath, fil)
      print p1, " to ", p2
      #sftp.get(p1,p2)
```

There is the Debug output from python.

```
INFO:paramiko.transport.sftp:[chan 1] Opened sftp connection (server version 3)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 1 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] Sesch channel 1 request ok
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 2] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] EOF received (1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 1] EOF sent (1)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 2] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Secsh channel 2 opened.
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:[chan 2] Sesch channel 2 request ok
DEBUG:paramiko.transport.sftp:[chan 1] listdir('md5sum_files')
10
[u'Checker_Checker_coin_queen_white.png_md5sum', u'Checker_Checker_coin_white.png_md5sum', u'Checker_Checker_coin_queen_brown.png_md5sum', u'Checker_Checker_coin_brown_selected.png_md5sum', u'Checker_Checker_coin_brown.png_md5sum', u'Checker_Checker_board.png_md5sum', u'Checker_Checker_coin_queen_brown_selected.png_md5sum', u'Checker_Checker_coin_white_selected.png_md5sum', u'Checker_Checker_coin_queen_white_selected.png_md5sum', u'Checker_Checker_background.png_md5sum']
Checker_Checker_coin_queen_white.png_md5sum
md5sum_files/Checker_Checker_coin_queen_white.png_md5sum  to  remote_md5sum_files\Checker_Checker_coin_queen_white.png_md5sum
Checker_Checker_coin_white.png_md5sum
md5sum_files/Checker_Checker_coin_white.png_md5sum  to  remote_md5sum_files\Checker_Checker_coin_white.png_md5sum
Checker_Checker_coin_queen_brown.png_md5sum
md5sum_files/Checker_Checker_coin_queen_brown.png_md5sum  to  remote_md5sum_files\Checker_Checker_coin_queen_brown.png_md5sum
Checker_Checker_coin_brown_selected.png_md5sum
md5sum_files/Checker_Checker_coin_brown_selected.png_md5sum  to  remote_md5sum_files\Checker_Checker_coin_brown_selected.png_md5sum
Checker_Checker_coin_brown.png_md5sum
md5sum_files/Checker_Checker_coin_brown.png_md5sum  to  remote_md5sum_files\Checker_Checker_coin_brown.png_md5sum
Checker_Checker_board.png_md5sum
md5sum_files/Checker_Checker_board.png_md5sum  to  remote_md5sum_files\Checker_Checker_board.png_md5sum
Checker_Checker_coin_queen_brown_selected.png_md5sum
md5sum_files/Checker_Checker_coin_queen_brown_selected.png_md5sum  to  remote_md5sum_files\Checker_Checker_coin_queen_brown_selected.png_md5sum
Checker_Checker_coin_white_selected.png_md5sum
md5sum_files/Checker_Checker_coin_white_selected.png_md5sum  to  remote_md5sum_files\Checker_Checker_coin_white_selected.png_md5sum
Checker_Checker_coin_queen_white_selected.png_md5sum
md5sum_files/Checker_Checker_coin_queen_white_selected.png_md5sum  to  remote_md5sum_files\Checker_Checker_coin_queen_white_selected.png_md5sum
Checker_Checker_background.png_md5sum
md5sum_files/Checker_Checker_background.png_md5sum  to  remote_md5sum_files\Checker_Checker_background.png_md5sum
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread

Process finished with exit code 0
```

## Edit:

Nervermind, i'm now testing from my home, the network is not as bad configuration as the other place, and it's seem that everything work. So i'm not sure but i think it was probably that.

Comment: it's said in paramiko.SFTP docs that listdir "does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the folder", maybe it will help, dunno :)

Comment: @GermanPetrov I'm not looking for '.' or '..', i'm looking for all files/directory in my directory (md5sum_files) so it's normal that i dont have 'md5sum_files/.' and 'md5sum_files/..' in the path (it's logical, isn't it? or i missed something?)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Actually I don't get an error like yours but listdir simply will not return more than 10000 files.